# What's involved in becoming a software architect?

Tags: architecture

I have been working as a Sr. developer for a while now and would like to transition to an architect role.  I wanted to know from those who are already in this role as to what knowledge does it require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2 cents (short version)...

As a developer, you implement systems. A junior developer is usually assigned specific tasks, and as you gain experience you start to do more and more design. Usually the technologies are determined for you.

An architect is someone who has lots of implementation experience, but concentrates more on design. A J2EE architect looks at an entire application and splits it up into layers/components. Then he/she determines which technologies to use for each. JSP vs JSF vs Spring for the front end ? JPA or Hybernate or JDBC for DB access? Whether or not to use EJBs? JMS? JTS? etc. The architect must determine funtional and non-functional requirements, and make sure that the system meets them. Non functional requirements are things like scalability, extensibility, maintenance, etc. Architects usually work with developers to make sure that the final code meets the desired specs.

An enterprise architect is yet another level up, taking into account all systems used by a company and helping to plan a roadmap for the company's future. There are several good books on the subject. Both books written by Sun and Oracle for the Java Architecture Certification test are excellent IMO and have application outside of the J2EE world, as they list the things an architect should consider while designing systems and interfaces.

Comment: so what you're saying is that it would be useful to have high level knowledge of how different systems work and what are used by the company/

Comment: Yeah, that's a start. Learn about the existing systems and how they inter-operate. Get an understanding of where the company is going from a business and technical perspective, and think about ways in which the existing infrastructure could be improved to support it. Be aware of latest technologies and technology trends. All that will make you more likely to be noticed at your current job and anywhere else you might want to apply.